# Why doesn't cyclic reference with singleton instance holder throw StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, circular-dependency

```
static class A {
    private static class InstanceHolder {
        private static final A a = new A();
    }

    private final B b;

    private A() {
        b = B.getInstance();
    }

    static A getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.a;
    }
}

static class B {
    private static class InstanceHolder {
        private static final B b = new B();
    }

    private final A a;

    private B() {
        a = A.getInstance();
    }

    static B getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = A.getInstance();
    B b = B.getInstance();
    System.out.println(a.b);
    System.out.println(b.a);
}
```

I'd expect that even indirect calls of constructors `A -> B -> A` would cause `StackOverflowError`.

Instead, the first object (`a`) has the reference to `b` initialized, while the second has the back-reference null.

Comment: `getInstance` doesn't call any other class's constructor.

Comment: `getInstance` indirectly reaches the field of `InstanceHolder`, which is `final` and was thus expected to call its initialization before returning. @RobertHarvey However see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061115/1429367 which describes the theory behind this well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The JVM tracks 'class initialization has started' and will never start it a second time. That's *why* this whole `InstanceHolder` song and dance routine works in the first place: You're using the JVM's concurrency gating mechanism that it applies to classloading, otherwise *none* of this would be useful at all.

Thus, you are **absolutely guaranteed** that the `new A()` in the static initializer sequence of class `A.InstanceHolder` is run at most once, *ever*.

Which raises the obvious question: Allright, soooo, what happens when a context accesses the `A.InstanceHolder` class when the static initialization procedure for `A.InstanceHolder` has started, but hasn't finished yet? Given that the JVM guarantees no re-running of initializers, the answer thus cannot possibly be 'stackoverflow', but what *does* happen then?

That breaks down into two separate scenarios:

1. The code that needs `A.InstanceHolder` to be initialized is running in a different thread. That is, *another thread* is in the middle of that initialization procedure (still going through the sequence of bytecode required to fulfill `new A()`, which is the static initialization code for `A.InstanceHolder`). In that case, this thread will simply block. It's like `synchronized` in just about every way.
2. The code that needs `A.InstanceHolder` to be initialized is already running in this thread. In other words, we need `A.InstanceHolder` to be initialized *in the middle of* the sequence of bytecode that.. is doing the very initialization we are now dependent on! In this case, the JVM spec is clear: Upon init, all fields are initialized to `null`/`0`/`false`, and initialization then proceeds. Any attempt to read from these fields before they are available simply returns the value they have (`null`/`0`/`false`), **even if they are final**. This does result in the somewhat bizarre situation that a `private static final String x = someMethodThatMakesX();` can nevertheless have `x` hold 2 different values (`null`, and the actual value), even though it is final. We can trivially witness this:

```
> cat ExampleOfClassInitWeirdness.java
public class ExampleOfClassInitWeirdness {
  private static final String y = hi();
  private static final String x = test();
  private static final String z = bye();

  public static String hi() {
    System.out.println(x); // compiles. Prints 'null'
    return null;
  }

  public static String test() {
    System.out.println(x); // compiles. Prints 'null'
    return "hello";
  }

  public static String bye() {
    System.out.println(x); // compiles. Prints '"hello"'.
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
> java ExampleOfClassInitWeirdness.java
null
null
hello
```

all 3 prints come from different places where the exact same java code exists: `System.out.println(x);`, and given that `x` is `final`, how can it print different values?

Well, it can - the JVM spec is clear, even if the result is a bit odd.

The same principle explains why you don't get a stack overflow error. The sequence goes as follows. I assume somewhere in your java code you wrote: `A.getInstance()`. Then:

- ClassLoader checks if `A` is loaded and what its init status is.
- ClassLoader concludes it isn't loaded and thus init status is `NEEDED`.
- ClassLoader finds the bytecode from the jar file or whatever and `defineClass`es the class into existence with it.
- ClassLoader now starts the initialization procedure. It atomically performs this operation: Check if the status is still `NEEDED`. It is, so, update to `INITIALIZING`, and keep track of the fact that this thread is doing the initialization. The initialization is trivial to non-existent; no `static{}` blocks and no expressions initializing static fields either. I'm going to skip explaining how `B` is initialized; it is similarly boring. `A`'s status becomes `INITIALIZED`.
- Remember, we were in the middle of running the opcode `INVOKESTATIC com.foo.pkg.A getInstance()Lcom/foo/pkg/A;`, and as part of that, we had to ensure A was loaded and initialized before proceeding. So, let's continue. The `A.getInstance()` can now run. This runs opcode `GETSTATIC com.foo.pkg.A$InstanceHolder a Lcom/foo/pkg/A;` and this, therefore, requires that `A$InstanceHolder` is loaded and initialized. It is not, so... off to the jar file we go to find the bytecode and load it, then time to initialize it; its status goes to `INITIALIZING` with this thread as initializer. All static fields are initialized to `null`/`0`/`false`.
- There is stuff to do - run the code `new A()`.
- This requires running code `B.getInstance()` (that's another `INVOKESTATIC` opcode).
- This causes `B` to need to be loaded and initialized. As discussed, boring, this happens.
- Run `B.getInstance()`. This causes `GETSTATIC` on `B$InstanceHolder` which means `B$InstanceHolder` needs to be loaded and initialized. It isn't.
- Begin the init procedure. Run the static initializers, which, here, is `new B()`.
- `new B()` does an `INVOKESTATIC` on `A.getInstance()`
- This requires `A` to be loaded and initialized. It is.
- We run `A.getInstance()`. This `GETSTATIC`s from `A$InstanceHolder`, which requires `A$InstanceHolder` to be loaded and initialized. It isn't; not quite - it is loaded, yes. but its status is `INITIALIZING`, not initialized. We're a few layers into the stack here, but this is all a chain of events caused by initializing `A$InstanceHolder`.
- The thread that is registered as doing the initializing is this thread, so we don't block, we just continue without modifying anything. We act as if the thing is already initialized. So, we just.. execute the `GETSTATIC` opcode. Which dutifully returns the current value. Which is `null`.
- `B.getInstance()` is now done. This instance's `a` field is now `null`.
- `new B()` is now done. And with that, the static init sequence of `A$InstanceHolder` is now done. The instance of `A` it made has a field of type `B`; the instance of `B` that fields hold has a field that holds an instance of `A`. That field holds `null`.
- `A.getInstance()` finishes and returns that instance for which `that.getB().getA()` is `null`.

One thing to understand is that `final` is **mostly** a figment of `javac`. The JVM mostly doesn't care about final and considers it a comment. The reason this:

```
public class Example {
  private static final Instant NOW = Instant.now();

  public static void breakThings() {
    NOW = null;
  }
}
```

Doesn't compile is because javac refuses to compile it. There is an `if` statement somewhere in javac that says: Uh, no. `NOW` is final, and you are attempting to write to it potentially more than once, so, no.

But just delete that if from the java code and it would compile and it would sorta run.

Unlike generics, which are truly *entirely* a comment from the JVM's perspective (it does not affect what the JVM does, whatsoever, it is **entirely** javac that cares about generics, which explains why you can't read them at runtime from instances), `final` is merely **mostly** a comment. There are certain concurrency rules and guarantees, as well as certain hotspot optimizations, that work differently.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot for the comprehensive explanation!